# Most efficient data structure for finding most frequent items

Tags: sorting, haskell, data-structures, word-frequency

I want to extract most frequent words from the [Google N-Grams dataset](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) which is about 20 GB in its uncompressed form. I don't want the whole data set resorted, just most frequent 5000 of them. But if I write

```
take 5000 $ sortBy (flip $ comparing snd) dataset
-- dataset :: IO [(word::String, frequency::Int)]
```

it's going to be an endless waiting. But what should I do instead?

I know there is [Data.Array.MArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html) package available for in-place array computation, but I cannot see any function for items modification on its documentation page. There is also [Data.HashTable.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables-1.2.0.2/docs/Data-HashTable-IO.html), but it's an unordered data structure.

I'd like to use simple [`Data.IntMap.Strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html) (with its convenient `lookupLE` function), but I don't think it would be very efficient because it produces a new map on each alteration. Could `ST` monad improve that?

**UPD:** I've also posted the final version of program on [CoreReview.SX](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96778).

Comment: If you only need an estimate you would do well by just random sampling (english words are zipf-distributed, so stop sampling when you observe such a distribution I guess). Otherwise you could use a hash table and maintain a `(maxCountSoFar, word)` tuple which you update as you increment the counters in your hash table

Comment: @jberryman No, I want process the entire dataset instead of estimation. The tuples you mention is what I want, but the dataset is extremely large, so I'm asking for the most efficient approach.

Comment: "estimation" is not really the right word actually. You'll probably get the right answer, but you won't know for sure. Also I'm not sure now that I think about it how random sampling would work on the n-gram dataset, since it's already capturing word frequency. Anyway, just use the hashtable approach then, which is optimal.

Comment: @jberryman I just want to get the most frequent words for further processing, not check their distribution.

Comment: How can you filter out the exactly most frequent words without effectively building a histogram? You can _approximate_ the number, try to take a look at links in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19802/top-k-frequent-items-in-data-stream

Comment: 9000: According to the type in in the example code above and the linked dataset description, the dataset contains the histogram, so firegurafiku doesn't need to generate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

- using `splitAt` to divide the data set into the first 5000 items and the rest.
- sort the first 5000 items by frequency (ascending)
- go through the rest

  - if a item has greater frequency than the lowest freq in the sorted items
  - drop the lowest frequency item from the sorted items
  - insert the new item in its proper place in the sorted items

The process then becomes effectively linear, though the coefficient is improved if you use a data structure for the sorted 5000 elements that has sublinear min-delete and insertion.

For example, using [`Data.Heap` from the `heap` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap-1.0.0/docs/Data-Heap.html):

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Heap hiding (splitAt)

mostFreq :: Int -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
mostFreq n dataset = final
  where
    -- change our pairs from (String,Int) to (Int,String)
    pairs = map swap dataset
    -- get the first `n` pairs in one list, and the rest of the pairs in another
    (first, rest) = splitAt n pairs
    -- put all the first `n` pairs into a MinHeap
    start = fromList first :: MinHeap (Int, String)
    -- then run through the rest of the pairs
    stop = foldl' step start rest
    -- modifying the heap to replace its least frequent pair
    -- with the new pair if the new pair is more frequent
    step heap pair = if viewHead heap < Just pair
                       then insert pair (fromJust $ viewTail heap)
                       else heap
    -- turn our heap of (Int, String) pairs into a list of (String,Int) pairs
    final = map swap (toList stop)
    swap ~(a,b) = (b,a)
```

Comment: The problem is that I know how to do it in an imperative language: just a linked list with binary search, but how to do that *efficiently* in pure functional Haskell?

Comment: @firegurafiku: A heap or a tree are efficiently 'mutable', in the sense that you create a new (updated) structure which reuses most of the previous structure, in sub-linear time (better than a linked list).

Comment: Make sure the counts get evaluated eagerly. If you let them be lazy, it'll eat many GB of RAM even for tiny datasets. (In the code above, I believe the `<` operator should prevent any space leaks.)

Comment: @rampion Thank you for your code! It look a bit cryptic, so let me test it first.

Comment: firegurafiku: added some comments. let me know if you can't follow anything.

Comment: @rampion: Surprisingly, this seems to be working with almost no additional memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Have you *tried* this or are you just *guessing*? Because many Haskell sort functions respect *laziness*  and when you ask for only the top 5000 they'll happily avoid sorting the rest of those elements.

Similarly, be very careful with "it produces a new map on each alteration". Most insert operations are going to be O(log n) on this sort of data structure, with n bounded to 5000: so you might be allocating ~30 new cells in the heap on each alteration, but that's not a particularly huge cost, certainly not as huge as 5000.

What you'd want instead, if `Data.List.sort` doesn't work well enough, is something like:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM

type Freq = Int
type Count = Int
data Summarizer x = Summ {tracking :: !IntMap [x], least :: !Freq, 
                        size :: !Count, size_of_least :: !Count }

inserting :: x -> Maybe [x] -> Maybe [x]
inserting x Nothing = Just [x]
inserting x (Just xs) = Just (x:xs)

sizeLimit :: Summarizer x -> Summarizer x
sizeLimit skip@(Summ strs f_l tot lst) 
    | tot - lst < 5000 = skip
    | otherwise        = Summ strs' f_l' tot' lst'
        where (discarded, strs') = IM.deleteFindMin strs
              (f_l', new_least) = IM.findMin dps'
              tot' = tot - length discarded
              lst' = length new_least

addEl :: (x, Freq) -> Summarizer x -> Summarizer x
addEl (str, f) skip@(Summ strs f_l tot lst)
    | i < f_l && tot >= 5000 = skip
    | otherwise              = sizeLimit $ Summ strs' f_l' tot' lst'
        where strs' = IM.alter (inserting str) f strs
              tot' = tot + 1
              f_l' = min f_l f
              lst' = case compare f_l f of LT -> lst; EQ -> lst + 1; GT -> 1
```

Notice that we store lists of strings to handle duplicate frequencies; we mostly skip updating, and when we *do* update it's an O(log n) operation to put the new element in and sometimes (depending on duplication again) an O(log n) operation to prune out the smallest elements, and an O(log n) operation to find the new smallest ones.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I understand that there is no chance for compiler to optimize the `take & sort` approach into completely different algorithm. Sorting would require loading the whole dataset into memory which is not affordable. But after you said that, I decided to actually measure performance for naive implementation and you implementation, as well as @rampion's one.

Comment: I've just tried your code in GHCi and, unfortunately, it issues two errors: `Not in scope: dps'` and `Not in scope: i`

Comment: Sorry, `dps'` should be `strs'` and `i` should be `f`. I didn't test it in GHCi; I just dumped my thoughts out into SO: you need something which limits the size less than 5000 so that it can grow to 5000 and then have the bottom-most elements chopped off, and you need to be able to add elements.

Comment: I've just figured out the fact that Haskell IO is increadibly slow. It seems like it's file reading and parsing that takes the most of time.

Comment: Indeed @firegurafiku, when you use the built-in `String` types, defined as `[Char]`, you create a pointer and memory cell for every character read in, which can take a while. Sometimes it seems like the compiler gets to skip this overhead; I don't know the internals that well. Usually people use the `ByteStream` type or so to make this faster.

Comment: Finally, I came to a solution using [`Data.Conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.4.2) for IO and @rampion's function. Sorry, I haven't tested your solution, because his answer seems to be simpler and has almost zero memory footprint. In contrast, when I implemented naive approach, the program, as I predicted, tried to allocate more memory then available and got terminated by operating system.